# What is the equivalent of bash indirect referencing ${!FOO} in zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, variable-substitution, for

`${!FOO}` performs a double substitution in `bash`, meaning it takes the (string) value of FOO and uses it as a variable name.
`zsh` doesn’t support this feature.

Is there a way to make this work the same in `bash` and `zsh`?

#### Background:

I’ve got a list of environment variables, like

```
PATH MAIL EDITOR
```

and want to first print the variable names and afterwards their values.

This works in `bash` but not `zsh`:

```sh
for VAR in LIST
do
        echo $VAR
        echo ${!VAR}
done
```

It should be somehow possible “the old way” with `eval`, but I can’t get it to work:

```sh
for VAR in LIST
do
        echo $VAR
        echo `eval \$$VAR`
done
```

I’m never going to understand why I can’t simply do arbitrary deep substitutions like `${${VAR}}` or even `${${${VAR}}}` if need be, so an explanation for that would be nice, too.

Comment: HAH! I thought zsh was supposed to have more features.

Comment: No need to brag with `bash`, it indeed has the same function (and a lot more), only uses a different pattern, namely `${(p)FOO}`.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин, zsh's `(e)` parameter expansion flag was added in zsh-2.6-beta17 (May 1996), the `(P)` flag in 3.1.5-pws-7 (1999). bash's `${!var}` in 2.0 (December 1996).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both bash and zsh have a way to perform indirect expansion, but they use different syntax.

It's easy enough to perform indirect expansion using `eval`; this works in all POSIX and most Bourne shells. Take care to quote properly in case the value contains characters that have a special meaning in the shell.

```
eval "value=\"\${$VAR}\""
echo "$VAR"
echo "$value"
```

`${${VAR}}` doesn't work because it's not a feature that any shell implements. The thing inside the braces must conform to syntax rules which do not include `${VAR}`. (In zsh, this is supported syntax, but does something different: nested substitutions perform successive transformations on the same value; `${${VAR}}` is equivalent to `$VAR` since this performs the identity transformation twice on the value.)

Answer (score 31):

The comment, under the original question, by Profpatsch gives the example `${(p)FOO}` to output the content of an indirect variable reference.  The flag is incorrect or a typo, it should be a capital P and not a lower case p.  Use: `${(P)FOO}`.

The following should produce the desired output:

```
#! /bin/zsh
LIST=(PATH MAIL EDITOR)
for VAR in ${LIST}
do
    print -r -- "${VAR}:  ${(P)VAR}"
done
```

From the *zshexpn* man page; section - *Parameter Expansion Flags*:

> P
>
> ```
>   This forces the value of the parameter name to be interpreted as a further
>   parameter name,  whose  value  will  be used where appropriate.  Note that
>   flags set with one of the typeset family of commands (in particular case
>   trans‐formations) are not applied to the value of name used in this fashion.
>
>   If used with a nested parameter or command substitution, the result of that
>   will be taken as a parameter  name  in the  same  way.   For  example,  if
>   you  have  `foo=bar'  and `bar=baz', the strings ${(P)foo}, ${(P)${foo}}, and
>   ${(P)$(echo bar)} will be expanded to `baz'
> ```

At one time I read why `${${${VAR}}}` does not produce the output you expected, but at this time I can't find it. You can do something like the following:

```
first="second" ; second="third" ; third="fourth" ; fourth="fifth"
print -r -- ${(P)${(P)${(P)first}}}
fifth
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not using eval correctly. In your example value of $VAR preceded with a "$" (i.e `$VALUE') would be executed as a command. That's not what you want. You want to evaluate the expansion of a variable whose name is taken from another variable.

```
$ for i in `echo PATH MAIL EDITOR`; 
    do eval moo="\${$i}" 
    echo $moo 
done
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/u (...)
/var/mail/root
nano
```

Answer (score 0):

### `{ba,z}sh` solution

Here's a function which works in both {ba,z}sh. I believe it's also POSIX compliant.

It warns when given:

- Null input
- More than one argument
- A variable name which isn't set

```
# Expand the variable named by $1 into its value. Works in both {ba,z}sh
# eg: a=HOME $(var_expand $a) == /home/me
var_expand() {
  if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || [ -z "${1-}" ]; then
    printf 'var_expand: expected one non-empty argument\n' >&2;
    return 1;
  fi
  eval printf '%s' "\"\${$1?}\""
}
```

Comment: There's no `function` nor `[[...]]` in POSIX `sh`.

Comment: The check for no argument should be with `[ "$#" -eq 0 ]` (or probably `[ "$#" -ne 1 ]` as you're expecting only one argument).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, updated. Is there a reference shell for POSIX compliance? I'm thinking `shell-check` might help too.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Re the test, I also want to want to fail when given a single null argument. I've added your 2nd suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: I agree with quoting `${1-}` given `a='"" -o -n 1'` `[ -z $a ]` == `0`.  But won't `$#` always be a single token?

Comment: In `zsh` yes (unless in sh/ksh emulation) but in Bourne-like shells, unquoted parameter expansions are subject to split+glob, so by not quoting it, you're adding an unnecessary dependency  for `$IFS` not to contain digits. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346), *What about `[ $# -gt 1 ]`* section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83790/discussion-between-tom-hale-and-stephane-chazelas).