# Double and triple substitution in bash and zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, variable-substitution

Follow-up to the background part in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68035/foo-and-zsh).

In `bash` I can use `${!FOO}` for double substitution, in `zsh` `${(P)FOO}`. In both, the old-school (hack-y) `eval \$$FOO` works.

So, the smartest and most logical thing for me would be `${${FOO}}, ${${${FOO}}}…` for double/triple/n substitution. Why doesn’t this work as expected?

Second: What does the `\` do in the `eval` statement? I reckon it’s an escape, making something like `eval \$$$FOO` impossible. How to do a triple/n substitution with that that works in every shell?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `\` must be used to prevent the expansion of `$$` (current process id). For triple substitution, you need double eval, so also more escapes to avoid the unwanted expansions in each eval:

```
#! /bin/bash
l0=value
l1=l0
l2=l1
l3=l2
l4=l3

echo $l0
eval echo \$$l1
eval eval echo \\$\$$l2
eval eval eval echo \\\\$\\$\$$l3
eval eval eval eval echo \\\\\\\\$\\\\$\\$\$$l4
```

Comment: Yet: `l3=l2; eval eval eval echo \\\$\\$\$$l3` → `53294` so not exactly modular.

Comment: Why can’t I do something like `eval $(eval echo \$$l2)`? I hate bash, it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Profpatsch: Added more examples.

Comment: Ah, it’s n². I don’t even want to try to get why it’s like this.

Comment: @Profpatsch: Easy. In each step, the number of backslashes halves (so it is 2ⁿ, in fact).

Comment: Wow, I shouldn’t confuse these two in my theoretical computer science exams…

Comment: I’m marking this as the correct answer now, since the title is how to do double and triple substitution. Gilles text is kind of the the missing part of the answer.

Answer (score 19):

```
#!/bin/bash

hello=world
echo=hello

echo $echo ${!echo}
```

Comment: That does not work in `zsh`.

Answer (score 8):

Supposing the value of `FOO` is a valid variable name (say `BAR`), `eval \$$FOO` splits the value of `BAR` into separate words, treats each word as a wildcard pattern, and executes the first word of the result as a command, passing the other words as arguments. The backslash in front of the dollar makes it be treated literally, so the argument passed to the `eval` builtin is the four-character string `$BAR`.

`${${FOO}}` is a syntax error. It doesn't do a “double substitution” because there's no such feature in any of the common shells (not with this syntax anyway). In zsh, `${${FOO}}` *is* valid and is a double substitution, but it behaves differently from what you'd like: it performs two successive transformations on the value of `FOO`, both of which are the identity transformation, so it's just a fancy way of writing `${FOO}`.

If you want to treat the value of a variable as a variable, be careful of quoting things properly. It's a lot easier if you set the result to a variable:

```
eval "value=\${$FOO}"
```

Comment: Setting it as variable, so that the first word isn’t used as command? Man, this sort of logic is hard to grasp. It’s the general problem I seem to have with bash.

Answer (score 7):

### `{ba,z}sh` solution

Here's a function which works in both `{ba,z}sh`. I believe it's also POSIX compliant.

Without going mad with quoting, you can use it for many levels of indirection like so:

```
$ a=b
$ b=c
$ c=d
$ echo $(var_expand $(var_expand $a)
d
```

Or if you have more (!?!) levels of indirection you could use a loop.

It warns when given:

- Null input
- A variable name which isn't set

```
# Expand the variable named by $1 into its value. Works in both {ba,z}sh
# eg: a=HOME $(var_expand $a) == /home/me
var_expand() {
  if [ -z "${1-}" ] || [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    printf 'var_expand: expected one argument\n' >&2;
    return 1;
  fi
  eval printf '%s' "\"\${$1?}\""
}
```

Comment: A working cross-shell solution for me. Hopefully "POSIX-compatible double variable expansion" redirects to this answer in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you need to do that?

You can always do it in several steps like:

```
eval "l1=\${$var}"
eval "l2=\${$l1}"
...
```

Or use a function like:

```
deref() {
  if [ "$1" -le 0 ]; then
    eval "$3=\$2"
  else
    eval "deref $(($1 - 1)) \"\${$2}\" \"\$3\""
  fi
}
```

Then:

```
$ a=b b=c c=d d=e e=blah
$ deref 3 a res; echo "$res"
d
$ deref 5 a res; echo "$res"
blah
```

FWIW, in `zsh`:

```
$ echo ${(P)${(P)${(P)${(P)a}}}}
blah
```

Comment: Huh, using several steps didn’t occur to me until now… strange.

Comment: It's obvious, from my point of view, why @Profpatsch wants to _do that_. Because it is the most intuitive way to do it. Being _hard_ to implement multiple substitutions in bash is another thing.

Answer (score 2):

Just like `${$foo}` doesn't work in place of `${(P)foo}` in `zsh`, neither does `${${$foo}}`. You just need to specify each level of indirection:

```
$ foo=bar
$ bar=baz
$ baz=3
$ echo $foo
bar
$ echo ${(P)foo}
baz
$ echo ${(P)${(P)foo}}
3
```

Of course, `${!${!foo}}` doesn't work in `bash`, because `bash` doesn't allow nested substitutions.

Comment: Thanks, that’s good to know. A shame that this is zsh-only, so you can’t really put it in a script (everyone has bash, but it’s not the other way around).

Comment: I suspect `zsh` is installed far more often than you might assume. It may not be linked to `sh` like `bash` often (but not always) is, but it may still be available for shell scripts. Think of it like you do Perl or Python.

Answer (score 2):

#### POSIX solution

Without going mad with quoting, you can use this function for many levels of indirection like so:

```
$ a=b
$ b=c
$ c=d
$ echo $(var_expand $(var_expand $a)
d
```

Or if you have more(!?!) levels of indirection you could use a loop.

It warns when given:

- Null input
- More than one argument
- A variable name which isn't set

```
# Expand the variable named by $1 into its value. Works in both {ba,z}sh
# eg: a=HOME $(var_expand $a) == /home/me
function var_expand {
  if [ "$#" -ne 1 ] || [ -z "${1-}" ]; then
    printf 'var_expand: expected one argument\n' >&2;
    return 1;
  fi
  eval printf '%s' "\"\${$1?}\""
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't combined this answer with your previous one? At a glance I don't see the difference between them.