# Is it possible to use indirection for setting variables?

Tags: bash

E.g. next script will print `Hello` due to `${!` rule.

```
A=B
B=Hello
echo ${!A}
```

But how can I **set** value to variable with indirect name? Straightforward use of `!` sign doesn't work:

```
A=B
!A=Hello # here is tricky line
echo $B
```

I know there is a trick with using temp file, but I'm interested in using indirection, not something like

```
A=B
echo "$A=Hello" > 1.tmp
. 1.tmp
echo $B
```

Comment: `eval $A=foobar`

Comment: Do you want to create synonyms so that both variables point to the same data? In other words when one changes, changes the other? I'm not sure I get your intention here.

Comment: no, I just wanted to set one variable through value of another once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way you could try:

```
$ A=B
$ read $A <<< 81
$ echo "$B"
81
```

But there is a security risk (!) as with all these methods (also `declare` / `typeset` and of course `eval`) .. In this case one must control the lefthand side (the value of `$A`), in other words, at least in `bash`, variable `$A` should not contain user controlled input, for example an input file, etcetera...

---

If your shell does not support a here-string ( `<<<` ) you could also use a here-document instead:

```
A=B
read $A << EOF
82
EOF
echo "$B"
```

Comment: wow, but why does it work?

Comment: The shell expands variable $A before the read command..

Comment: The only issue: it doesn't work on Solaris

Comment: What version of bash on Solaris are you referring to? On what version of Solaris?

Comment: Solaris 10, bash from the box

Comment: I just tried this in bash 3.00 on Solaris 10 and it worked. Are you certain you using bash? If so what version is it?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 2.05.0(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.4)`. Maybe I just have old bash, or it's Sparc Solaris issue. Tried on i586 solaris and it worked (with bash 3 although). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You could try a here-document instead of a here-string, see the edit in my post..

Comment: This is not a good method. It's complex, and it breaks if there are special characters in the value (newlines, backslashes and leading or trailing whitespace on a line are problematic).

Comment: This isn't a good method, but your note about controlling variable names within a program is right on.

Comment: Depending on your bash version, it may also support `A=B; read -r $A < <( echo "81" ) ; echo $B` All the same security points above still apply.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this with the `typeset` builtin:

```
$ A=B
$ typeset $A=42
$ echo $B
42
```

Or using `declare`:

```
$ declare $A=1
$ echo $B
1
```

Comment: In `bash`, `typeset` is obsolete and its replacement is `declare`.  They are more or less identical.

Comment: `typeset` is a bit more portable though (works in ksh)

Comment: thanks! Can't decide which answer is better. Flipped a coin :)

Answer (score 9):

Following on [indirection when getting the value of a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68042/double-and-triple-substitution-in-bash-and-zsh/68272#68272)…

The portable way is to use `eval`. You do have to pay attention to the quoting so that special characters in the value are not evaluated when they shouldn't be. The easiest way is to store the new value in an intermediate variable and assign the value of that variable.

```
A=B
tmp='stuff with special characters or whatever…'
eval $A=\$tmp
```

The argument to `eval` is `B=$tmp`, a straightforward assignment. You don't need double quotes around `$tmp` even if it contains whitespace or globbing characters, because those are not expanded in an assignment.

If you want to make an environment variable, you can use `export`. In bash or ksh or zsh, you can use `typeset` to make a local variable (`declare` is synonymous in bash). Again, you should use an intermediate variable so that special characters are not mangled. Note that except in zsh, you need to put double quotes around the variable expansion, because this is not an assignment but a builtin that takes an argument that happens to look like an assignment.

```
export $A="$tmp"
```

Comment: This (using `eval`) is the correct answer.  It's portable, adheres to the POSIX standard, and is the one used all over the place in more advanced shell scripts.  One thing, though: using `export` on the same line as the assignment is _not_ portable.

Comment: @MadScientist `export var=value` is POSIX. It isn't portable to Bourne shells, but these are a vanishing breed (just make sure to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/sh` or ksh and not `/bin/sh` on older Solaris machines).

Answer (score 2):

In bash version 5 I use `declare -n varref=varname`. Then variable could be set as `varref=123` and read as `echo $varref` (does the same as `echo $varname`) without any additional commands and syntax.

from `help declare`:

> `-n make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is with `printf`, which assigns its output to a variable whose name may be passed with the `-v` parameter:

```
A=B
printf -v "$A" '%s' "Hello"
echo ${!A}
```