# How can I assign the output of a command to different variables in each loop iteration?

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

I have a script something like this:

```bash
for chain in http https ssh
do
 iptables -nvxL $chain | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
done
```

But what I actually want to do is capture the output of the `iptables` command for each iteration into a different variable, whose *name* should be the equal to the current value of `chain`.

So for the first loop iteration (where `$chain` is `http`) I want this to happen:

```
http=$(iptables -nvxL http | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Then for the next I want this:

```
https=$(iptables -nvxL https | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Hopefully you get the idea, not sure how to do this.

Comment: You could do `awk 'END {print $2}'` in place of `tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case, I would use an associative array for that:

```bash
declare -A rules

for chain in http https ssh
do
   rules[$chain]=$(iptables -nvxL $chain | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')
done
```

You can then access the output by dereferencing, as in

```
printf -- "%s\n" "${rules['http']}"
```

or

```
for chain in http https ssh
do
    printf -- "%s\n" "${rules[$chain]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The associative array answer is almost certainly how you want to do this.

However if you literally want variables named `http`, `https`, and `ssh` (that you would reference with `$http`, `$https`, and $`ssh`), then you can use `printf -v` to assign the command output to a variable whose name is contained in `$chain`:

```
for chain in http https ssh; do
    printf -v "$chain" '%s' "$(iptables -nvxL "$chain" | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')"
done
```

Note also, as per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68349/34061), you can use `typeset` or `declare` to achieve the same thing:

```
for chain in http https ssh; do
    typeset "$chain"="$(iptables -nvxL "$chain" | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')"
done
```

No `eval`s were harmed in the making of this answer.  Also, if you want to print the variable values from a loop as in @penguin359's answer, you can use [bash variable indirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to dereference the variable names - again, no `eval`s needed:

```
for chain in http https ssh; do
    echo ${!chain}
done
```

Comment: @JoL there, I fixed it, using a `printf -v` to do the assignment.  Much cleaner than an eval, I think.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I forgot to quote the embedded `$2` in the example. It should now work as requested by the OP. Also, the point behind this answer and the use of `eval` is to provide a portable example using standard Bourne shell syntax across multiple different implementations. I have tested all the following code across bash, dash, and zsh. Dash is a better test of portability as it uses a much more limited and more true to Bourne shell syntax. It is also the default shell on Debian/Ubuntu for `/bin/sh`. The `typeset` and `printf -v` do not exist in Dash. I do think `eval` is ugly, but it was the first mechanism in Bourne shell and is the best method for true portability.

While I think that associative arrays are the way to go, I want to provide an exact answer to his original question and one that is portable to other Bourne shells besides Bash. This here would be how dynamic variable names would be done traditionally:

```
for chain in http https ssh; do
    eval $chain="\"\$(iptables -nvxL $chain | tail -1 | awk '{print \$2}')\""
done
```

The `eval` operator in Bourne shell is used to substitute variables into a command and then re-run (re-evaluate) it as a command after that is complete. After the first substitution of that command, the $chain variable and first set of quoting is completed leaving it to look like this:

```
http="$(iptables -nvxL http | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')"
```

Which then evaluates as a variable assignment to a command expansion of `iptables`. Since the inner command used single-quotes, I couldn't use them to quote the `eval` statement, hence the use of `"\"` and `\""` to quote it for eval and to pass the double and single quotes through as needed in the resulting command. The double-quotes around the command expansion might not be needed, but I have run into issues with some shell if the command expands into multiple words. To dump out the contents of these, do something similar:

```
for chain in http https ssh; do
    eval echo \$$chain
done
```

The first dollar-sign is quoted and passed though. This results in the following three commands being executed after the loop is un-rolled:

```
echo $http
echo $https
echo $ssh
```

Comment: I'm sure you're aware, `eval` is usually considered evil, for its exciting code-insertion properties.  In this case, we can do all of the above with `printf`/`typeset`/`declare` and variable indirection, instead of `eval`.

Comment: Yes, but it is not portable. I learned new things from your answer that I might use, but it does presume the use of Bash and is not a valid approach if you need to write a script that might run on other Bourne shell derivatives. Eval is hard to do right, but I wouldn't trust any shell script when privilege escalation might be a concern.