# zsh equivalent for bash's ${!variable}

Tags: bash, zsh

I just stumbled over a script with works in bash but not in zsh:

```
if [ Darwin = `uname` ]; then
   library_path=DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
   library_path=LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
if [ -z "${!library_path}" ]; then
   eval ${library_path}=${thisdir}/lib64:${thisdir}/lib; export ${library_path}
else
   eval ${library_path}=${thisdir}/lib64:${thisdir}/lib:${!library_path}; export ${library_path}
fi
```

the second if should apparently test, depending on the kernel, if `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is non zero, or if `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is non zero. And then either set or expand the respective variable.

How would I do the same in zsh? And is there a version that works in zsh and bash?

Comment: Related: [${!FOO} and zsh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68035/foo-and-zsh)

Answer (score 0):

It appears `$(eval echo \$\{$library_path\})` works:

```
if [ Darwin = `uname` ]; then
   library_path=DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
else
   library_path=LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
if [ -z $(eval echo \$\{$library_path\}) ]; then
   eval ${library_path}=${thisdir}/lib64:${thisdir}/lib; export ${library_path}
else
   eval ${library_path}=${thisdir}/lib64:${thisdir}/lib:$(eval echo \$\{$library_path\}); export ${library_path}              
fi
```

though there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: That's wrong (and potentially dangerous) as you're also evaluating the content of `$thisdir` as shell code as well . You also don't need to use `echo` or process substitution (especially unquoted!) here.

Comment: See the dup Q&A for [the zsh equivalent of bash's `${!var}`](/a/119442) or the [proper way to use `eval`](/a/68271)