# What does the substitution ${!var_name+x} mean?

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

I found a script that has a function that checks if a variable is set but i don't understand it very well.

```
check_if_variable_is_set() {
    var_name=$1
    if [ -z "${!var_name+x}" ]; then
        false
    else
        true
    fi
}
```

What exactly happens with this substitution ?

Comment: related [${!FOO} and zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68035/72456).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the `bash` shell, `${!var}` is a variable indirection.  It expands to the value of the variable whose name is kept in `$var`.

The variable expansion `${var+value}` is [a POSIX expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) that expands to `value` if the variable `var` is set (no matter if its value is empty or not).

Combining these, `${!var+x}` would expand to `x` if the variable whose name is kept in `$var` is set.

Example:

```
$ foo=hello
$ var=foo
```

```
$ echo "${!var+$var is set, its value is ${!var}}"
foo is set, its value is hello
```

```
$ unset foo
$ echo "${!var+$var is set, its value is ${!var}}"
```

(empty line as output)

---

The function in the question could be shortened to

```
check_if_variable_is_set () { [ -n "${!1+x}" ]; }
```

or even:

```
check_if_variable_is_set () { [ -v "$1" ]; }
```

or even:

```
check_if_variable_is_set()[[ -v $1 ]]
```

Where `-v` is a `bash` test on a variable name which will be true if the named variable is set, and false otherwise.

---

POSIXly, it could be written:

```
check_if_variable_is_set() { eval '[ -n "${'"$1"'+x}" ]'; }
```

Note that all those are potential command injection vulnerabilities if the argument to that function could end up being under control of an attacker. Try for instance with `check_if_variable_is_set 'a[$(id>&2)]'`.

To guard against that, you may want to  verify that the argument is a valid variable name first. For variables:

```
check_if_variable_is_set() {
  case $1 in
    ("" | *[![:alnum:]_]* | [![:alpha:]_]*) false;;
    (*)  eval '[ -n "${'"$1"'+x}" ]'
  esac
}
```

(note that `[[:alpha:]]` will check for alphabetical characters *in your locale* while some shells only accept alphabetical characters from the portable character set in their variable)

Comment: There is nothing on earth more complete than this. You deserve a cookie for that.

Comment: @KarimManaouil A third of that cookie goes to Stéphane though :-)